# preloading images and having a buffer symbol

Tags: javascript, image

ok so I need to preload images with javascript and that code is here..

```
function mainSlideshow(){
    if(document.images){
        var pic1 = new Image(605, 403);
        pic1.src = "images/main_photo1.jpg";
        var pic2 = new Image(605, 403);
        pic2.src = "images/main_photo2.jpg";
        var pic3 = new Image(605, 403);
        pic3.src = "images/main_photo3.jpg";
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is display a buffering symbol until they are loaded.  How can I check to see if all the images are loaded and how can I make sure the buffering symbol is being displayed while they are loading?

Answer (score 0):

use onLoad event of image object. It is called when image finish loading

Comment: ok but how exactly would i use onLoad in this situation?  I don't plan on doing anything with the photos until they are all loaded.  doesn't onload need to be in an <img> tag?

Comment: onLoad needs to be in image tag or object. you show a message that images are loading, when onload event is called then stop showing that message.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the buffering image as the background for the container for your photos?